# Keras model optimization of 2D arrays

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a CNN with 2D arrays of normalized numbers.

Example of 2D training array:

```
36,36,37,37,38,38,39,39,39,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,40,41,41,41,41,41,42,42,42,42,43,43,44,44,45,45,46,47,49,51,54,56,58,61
10,10,10,10,10,11,11,11,11,11,11,12,12,12,12,12,13,13,13,13,14,14,14,14,14,15,15,15,15,16,16,16,16,17,17,18,19,19,20,21
```

With the following model I get decent results when testing but as I'm still pretty new to ML I am unsure of which layers,
filters and pooling are best suited for the dataset

I have run several hyperparameter optimizations but the actual layers and their individual settings are more difficult 
for me to try and optimize so any advice in getting a decent model for my type of data or just a nudge in the right direction 
would be much appreciated.

***So all-in-all my question is: How do I know when my model is designed in the best possible way? Is there some way I can test/brute-force all the different settings (model layers, filters, pooling etc.) to obtain the best model/final result?***

The model:

```
model=Sequential()


# CNN 1
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(2, 2), activation='relu', input_shape=(2, 40, 1), padding='same' ))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1, 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

# CNN 2
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(2, 2), activation='relu', padding='same' ))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 1), strides=(1, 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

# CNN 3
model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same' ))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 1), strides=(1, 1)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Flatten())

#Dense 1
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

#Dense 2
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

# Output
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))


model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=SGD(lr = 0.001, decay=0.0, momentum=0.9), metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The training:

```
Train on 15 samples, validate on 7 samples
Epoch 1/40
15/15 [==============================] - 1s 81ms/step - loss: 1.0414 - acc: 0.1889 - val_loss: 0.8904 - val_acc: 0.2143
Epoch 2/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 532us/step - loss: 0.9349 - acc: 0.2000 - val_loss: 0.7926 - val_acc: 0.2619
Epoch 3/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 532us/step - loss: 0.8128 - acc: 0.2111 - val_loss: 0.7212 - val_acc: 0.3333
Epoch 4/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 598us/step - loss: 0.7302 - acc: 0.3778 - val_loss: 0.6571 - val_acc: 0.5952
Epoch 5/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 532us/step - loss: 0.6573 - acc: 0.7444 - val_loss: 0.6054 - val_acc: 0.7381
Epoch 6/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 598us/step - loss: 0.5965 - acc: 0.7889 - val_loss: 0.5694 - val_acc: 0.8095
Epoch 7/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 665us/step - loss: 0.5571 - acc: 0.8000 - val_loss: 0.5513 - val_acc: 0.8333
Epoch 8/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 599us/step - loss: 0.5409 - acc: 0.8111 - val_loss: 0.5380 - val_acc: 0.8333
Epoch 9/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 599us/step - loss: 0.5269 - acc: 0.8111 - val_loss: 0.5249 - val_acc: 0.8333
Epoch 10/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 532us/step - loss: 0.5121 - acc: 0.8222 - val_loss: 0.5125 - val_acc: 0.8333
Epoch 11/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 515us/step - loss: 0.4976 - acc: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.5014 - val_acc: 0.8333
Epoch 12/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 598us/step - loss: 0.4841 - acc: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.4919 - val_acc: 0.8333
Epoch 13/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 598us/step - loss: 0.4717 - acc: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.4823 - val_acc: 0.8333
Epoch 14/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 598us/step - loss: 0.4603 - acc: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.4725 - val_acc: 0.8333
Epoch 15/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 598us/step - loss: 0.4492 - acc: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.4629 - val_acc: 0.8333
Epoch 16/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 665us/step - loss: 0.4386 - acc: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.4539 - val_acc: 0.8333
Epoch 17/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 598us/step - loss: 0.4284 - acc: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.4462 - val_acc: 0.8333
Epoch 18/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 599us/step - loss: 0.4204 - acc: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.4390 - val_acc: 0.8333
Epoch 19/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 665us/step - loss: 0.4128 - acc: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.4320 - val_acc: 0.8333
Epoch 20/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 601us/step - loss: 0.4052 - acc: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.4256 - val_acc: 0.8333
Epoch 21/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 598us/step - loss: 0.3977 - acc: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.4195 - val_acc: 0.8333
Epoch 22/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 532us/step - loss: 0.3907 - acc: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.4133 - val_acc: 0.8333
Epoch 23/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 661us/step - loss: 0.3838 - acc: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.4074 - val_acc: 0.8333
Epoch 24/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 732us/step - loss: 0.3770 - acc: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.4017 - val_acc: 0.8333
Epoch 25/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 665us/step - loss: 0.3704 - acc: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.3960 - val_acc: 0.8333
Epoch 26/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 533us/step - loss: 0.3640 - acc: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.3902 - val_acc: 0.9048
Epoch 27/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 532us/step - loss: 0.3577 - acc: 0.8333 - val_loss: 0.3846 - val_acc: 0.9286
Epoch 28/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 597us/step - loss: 0.3515 - acc: 0.8556 - val_loss: 0.3790 - val_acc: 0.9286
Epoch 29/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 531us/step - loss: 0.3454 - acc: 0.8889 - val_loss: 0.3734 - val_acc: 0.9762
Epoch 30/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 533us/step - loss: 0.3393 - acc: 0.9111 - val_loss: 0.3680 - val_acc: 0.9762
Epoch 31/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 532us/step - loss: 0.3333 - acc: 0.9556 - val_loss: 0.3625 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 32/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 597us/step - loss: 0.3274 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.3570 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 33/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 664us/step - loss: 0.3218 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.3514 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 34/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 599us/step - loss: 0.3162 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.3457 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 35/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 532us/step - loss: 0.3103 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.3388 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 36/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 531us/step - loss: 0.3028 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.3310 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 37/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 532us/step - loss: 0.2943 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.3231 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 38/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 595us/step - loss: 0.2857 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.3154 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 39/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 532us/step - loss: 0.2773 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.3082 - val_acc: 1.0000
Epoch 40/40
15/15 [==============================] - 0s 535us/step - loss: 0.2694 - acc: 1.0000 - val_loss: 0.3014 - val_acc: 1.0000
22/22 [==============================] - 0s 680us/step
```

Model summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 3, 20, 64)         320
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 2, 19, 64)         0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 2, 19, 64)         0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 2, 19, 128)        32896
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 2, 19, 128)        0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 2, 19, 128)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 2, 19, 128)        16512
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 2, 19, 128)        0
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 2, 19, 128)        0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 4864)              0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 64)                311360
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 32)                2080
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_5 (Dropout)          (None, 32)                0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 6)                 198
=================================================================
Total params: 363,366
Trainable params: 363,366
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________

Train score: 0.27449503540992737
Train accuracy: 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

> So all-in-all my question is: How do I know when my model is designed in the best possible way?

You can't. The pithiest explanation is "All models are wrong, but some are useful." This is discussed here [What is the meaning of "All models are wrong, but some are useful"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/57407/what-is-the-meaning-of-all-models-are-wrong-but-some-are-useful)
and here
[Are all models useless? Is any exact model possible -- or useful?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144475/are-all-models-useless-is-any-exact-model-possible-or-useful)

> Is there some way I can test/brute-force all the different settings (model layers, filters, pooling etc.) to obtain the best model/final result?

You could try to brute-force the search for a good model configuration, but how would you be confident that the end result *really* is optimal? There's always another model configuration that *could* be better.

Moreover, out-of-sample validation is used to assess generalization, but the more models you fit, the higher your risk of overfitting the out-of-sample data.
This is also addressed here: [Why is information about the validation data leaked if I evaluate model performance on validation data when tuning hyperparameters?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/384703/why-is-information-about-the-validation-data-leaked-if-i-evaluate-model-performa/384706#384706)

## so what do I do?

The more useful question to ask is whether the model is sufficient for your purpose: what problem are you trying to solve? Does this model solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Model architecture are application dependent. If you want to have spatial relation, then we prefer Convolutional network (CNN) and if you want to have temporal relation in data( like in text ), then use Recurrent network (RNN). But in this case you can also use **CONV1D**, it has given comparable result too.

Now, coming to your question, for designing part, you have to be clear about, what you want to do? In this case, you  can also try 1D-CNN, which have kernel size same as the input length.

You can also use Auto-ML for automating things, where you need to define your data-set, it will find optimal architecture for us by trying different-2 setting. For more info, you can look at https://autokeras.com/.

But as you are new to field, i would say, try it by yourself. The model architecture is art and it come by experience.